# How can i redirect the page in razor view .cshtml?

Tags: razor

`@{Response.Redirect("Index","Home")};`

The above code does not work please help me.

Comment: Why do you use it in you view? You want to have a link to direct you to your home page? or you want to trigger a redirect automatically?

Comment: i want to redirect directly....

Comment: The redirect is suppose to occur right when the view is called?

Comment: The corresponding button click...

Comment: So can I expect that you don't need to display any dynamic data in the page you are going to redirect to? means the target page is a static html? because if your page requires some dynamic data from db, there is no way for you get them if you redirect directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.Redirect` is a server-side operation and makes little sense to use in a view. You are after an appropriate client-side operation.

You can simply change `window.location.href` in Javascript (client-side) to redirect the browser and use `Url.Action` to generate (server-side) an appropriate client-side URL in your JavaScript.

e.g. something like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="function(){window.location.href=@(Url.Action("Index", Home"))}" value="Press Me!"/>
```

*Quite frankly though, you probably just want a link to your home-page that looks like a button as there is no advantage to using a `location.href` redirect in this situation.*